# How can I retrieve the authentication data of a user when using a Firebase callable function?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

My mobile app built in Flutter uses google login to register users. From within this app I am calling a Firebase cloud function (called questionAnswer) using the [Cloud Functions Plugin for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_functions).

If I understand correctly from [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) documentation, the https request should automatically include the Firebase authentication of the user.

How can I retrieve the authentication information of the user from within the Cloud Function? I need it in order to access data associated with that specific user in a Firebase Cloud Database. Should I include the google auth token as a parameter in the https request?

**Here is my code in the Flutter app:**

```
final HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(
      functionName: 'questionAnswer',
  );

 fetchHttps() async {
   dynamic resp = await callable.call();
   print(resp);
 }
```

**This is the code in the Cloud Function**

```
exports.questionAnswer = functions.https.onCall(() => {
  console.log('addNumbersLog', "holaLog");
    return answer;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function), auth information is in the second parameter passed to the function.  You will need to declare and use it:

```
exports.questionAnswer = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log('addNumbersLog', "holaLog");
  console.log(context.auth);
  return answer;
});
```

`context` here is a [CallableContext](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.callablecontext) object.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the `uid` of the user from the [`CallableContext`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.callablecontext#auth) parameter, which is passed to your [`onCall`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_#handler:-function) handler as the second argument.

From there on you can retrieve the Firebase [`UserRecord`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord) using the [`.getUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getuser) method and passing in the `uid`.

```js
exports.questionAnswer = functions.https.onCall((data, { auth }) => {
    admin.auth().getUser(auth.uid)
      .then((userRecord) => {
        // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
        console.log('Successfully fetched user data:', userRecord.toJSON());
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
      });
  });
});
```